# xlsx to xml Python script TypeError

Tags: python, xml, unicode, typeerror, xlsx

I'm working on converting xlsx rows into individual xml files. I had the script working, bit now trying to run it I get `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found` error pointing to line 49:

```
for f in files:
    current = open(f["Filename"],"w")
```

I'm new to python and not entirely sure what's going on, any suggestions?

Full code here:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from lxml import etree

    EXCEL_SPREADSHEET = raw_input("EXCEL SPREAD SHEET FILENAME: ")
    wb = load_workbook(filename=EXCEL_SPREADSHEET, read_only=True)
    ws = wb['Sheet1']

    files = []
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3):
            count = 0
            dict = {}
            for cell in row:
                count+= 1
                if count % 16 == 1:
                    dict["Filename"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 2:
                    dict["Title"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 3:
                    dict["Creators"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 4:
                    dict["Subjects"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 5:
                    dict["Description"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 6:
                    dict["Publisher"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 7:
                    dict["Contributors"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 8:
                    dict["Date"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 9:
                    dict["Type"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 10:
                    dict["Format"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 11:
                    dict["Identifier"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 12:
                    dict["Source"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 13:
                    dict["Language"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 14:
                    dict["Relation"] = cell.value
                elif count % 16 == 15:
                    dict["Coverage"] = cell.value
                else:
                    dict["Rights"] = cell.value
            files.append(dict)

    for f in files:
        current = open(f["Filename"],"w")
        #page = etree.Element("  will use lxml later
        current.write('''<oai_dc:dc xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">''')
        try:
            current.write("<dc:title>"+f["Title"]+"</dc:title>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            creators = f["Creators"].split(";")
            for creator in creators:
                current.write("<dc:creator>"+creator+"</dc:creator>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            subjects = f["Subjects"].split(";")
            for subject in subjects:
                current.write("<dc:subject>"+subject+"</dc:subject>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            contributors = f["Contributors"].split(";")
            for contributor in contributors:
                current.write("<dc:contributor>"+contributor+"</dc:contributor>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            current.write("<dc:description>"+f["Description"]+"</dc:description>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            current.write("<dc:date>"+f["Date"]+"</dc:date>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            types = f["Type"].split(";")
            for type in types:
                current.write("<dc:type>"+type+"</dc:type>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            current.write("<dc:format>"+f["Format"]+"</dc:format>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            current.write("<dc:identifier>"+f["Identifier"]+"</dc:identifier>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            current.write("<dc:source>"+f["Source"]+"</dc:source>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            current.write("<dc:language>"+f["Language"]+"</dc:language>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            current.write("<dc:relation>"+f["Relation"]+"</dc:relation>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            current.write("<dc:coverage>"+f["Coverage"]+"</dc:coverage>")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            current.write("<dc:rights>"+f["Rights"]+"</dc:rights>")
        except:
            pass
        current.write("</oai_dc:dc>")
        print "In progress... completed one file..."
    print "Completed"
```

Comment: Could you try printing out what is stored in `f["Filename"]`? It seems like from the error that it might think that cell's value is a list instead of a string for what it is expecting.

Comment: You should also make sure to do `current.close()` after you are done with each file. You can instead do `with open(f["Filename"], "w") as current:` as an outer block which will close the file for you after the statements finish inside the code block.

Comment: Show the **full** Traceback, so we can verify the source of the `TypeError`

Comment: @Karl I looked at the file some more and there were extra columns added off screen that were causing the error, probably from a bad copy paste job when the sheet was made. It works fine now.  Thanks for the close suggestion too, I'll make sure to add that.